# Angularjs Export to Excel - doesn't work in IE, and excel not proper in ff and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, excel, jsp

I have been trying to Export a table from a jsp page to Excel using AngularJs.

Will Angularjs not work in IE? and also getting this error `SCRIPT5009: 'Node' is undefined`

In Chrome and Firefox, the excel is getting opened only when i save it and not with `open with` option. The saved Excel is not proper. Trying to solve this for weeks.

Even tried using Jquery, but no luck. 
Please suggest me a solution.Really grateful.

My jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/Pulse/static/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr><td>
    <p ng-click="exportData()" id="myImg">Click here</p>
    </td></tr>
</table>
    <div id="exportable">
    <table width="100%" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Num</th>
                <th>Sq</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

My angularjs:

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.exportData = function() {
        var blob = new Blob(
                [ document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML ],
                {
                    type : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
                });
        window.saveAs(blob, "MyRep.xls");
    }
});
</script>
```

i get this, when clicking on `open with` excel in firefox:

[image]
On opening the saved excel :

[image]

Can anyone please point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Piyush Khatri Can you please tell, Is it even possible to use angularjs for export to excel in IE?

Answer (score 0):

you can prube this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $http,$timeout) {

$scope.exportData = function() {
    $timeout(function () {
        var blob = new Blob([ document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML ],
        {
            type : "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        });
    saveAs(blob, "MyRep.xls");}, 2000);
}
```

});

i guess that run good in firefox

and i have this others scripts in my page where i use

```
<link href="~/Content/Controls/AngularStrap/libs.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><script src="~/Content/Controls/AngularStrap/angular-strap.min.js"></script><script src="~/Content/Controls/AngularStrap/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script><script src="~/Content/Controls/FileSaver/FileSaver.js"></script>
```